# python: cannot import name beam_runner_api_pb2

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-beam

I am relatively new to Python and Beam and I have followed the Apache Beam - Python Quickstart ([here](https://beam.apache.org/get-started/quickstart-py/)) to the last letter.  My Python 2.7 virtual environment was created with conda.

I cloned the example from https://github.com/apache/beam

When I try to run

```
python -m apache_beam.examples.wordcount --input sample_text.txt --output counts
```

I get the following error

```
/Users/name/anaconda3/envs/py27/bin/python: cannot import name beam_runner_api_pb2
```

(which after searching I understand means that there is a circular import)

I have no idea where to begin.  Is this a bug or something wrong with my setup.

(I have now tried redoing the example in three different virtual environments - all with the same result)

Comment: It seems I did not correctly install the Google Cloud Platfrom (gcp) components as follows: # As part of the initial setup, install Google Cloud Platform specific extra components.
pip install apache-beam[gcp]

Answer (score 0):

It seems it was my mistake.  I did not correctly install the Google Cloud Platfrom (gcp) components.  Once I did this it all worked

```
# As part of the initial setup, install Google Cloud Platform specific extra components.
pip install apache-beam[gcp]
```